# Excel – formula to increase number with a letter

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to create an Excel formula that automatically creates the next number with a letter at the beginning.
A0001, A0002, A0003, ...
Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

A simpler (and more easily generalized) solution is

```
=TEXT(n, "A0000")
```

where *`n`* is the number you want to display
(perhaps using one of the suggestions from [Bandersnatch’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/1277682/150988#1277695)),
e.g.,

```
=TEXT(ROWS($1:1), "A0000")
```

The second argument to `TEXT()` is a display format
in the style of the ones you get
when you click on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> (“Format Cells”),
go to the “Number” tab
(it’s the first one, so it will typically come up by default)
and click on “Custom”.

Comment: Now *that's* elegant. And ingenious. I'd give it a +2 but it keeps refusing the second one, no matter how many times I try.  :-)

Comment: Thanks; it’s the thought that counts. (And I *think* that’s a *double entendre*, but I’m not sure.)

Answer (score 3):

Use this formula filled down from A1:

`="A"&REPT(0,3-TRUNC(ROW()/10))&ROW()`

If you need to start in some other row, replace the ROW() functions with (ROW()-x), where x is one less than the row you need to start in.

[image]

Comment: To start anywhere, use `ROWS($1:1)` in place of `ROW()`

Comment: That's a great improvement to this answer, and I should have thought of it.  Thanks.  :-)

Comment: Jhaqkey, if you found this useful, please click the check mark to accept this answer and remove it from the "unanswered" queue.  Thanks.

Comment: +1 for ingenuity.  (0 for elegance.)    :-)    ⁠

Answer (score 0):

In cell A1, put in 'A0001.

In the next row (B1):

=LEFT(A1,1)&TEXT(RIGHT(A1,4)+1,"0000")